# Mandatory argument for script to run java program

Tags: linux, shell-script, java, arguments

My script is called: `report_startDate`

It has the following line:

```
$JRE_ROOT/bin/java -cp /home/me/report/config/:/home/me/report/jar/reporting-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar  com.me.project.report.Main $1
```

`$1` makes it possible to for me to run the script as: `./report_startDate 20140717`.

But the script also runs without the date. I want to make it mandatory for whoever runs this script to supply the date.

What could I replace `$1` with to make it mandatory to supply date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this at the top:

```
if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    echo "Argument required."
    exit
fi
```

`-z` tests the argument string to see if it is of zero length.

If it's not zero length, execution will continue.