# How to run Java program in Bash script and give it one argument?

Tags: shell-script, directory, caja

I will add an item on a context menu, called "**Open with ABC**".
This context menu appear when I *right-clicked* a folder.

When the "**Open with ABC**" is selected, it will launch a Java program, "***abc.class***".

That Java program need "***directory path***" of that chosen folder, as *argument*.

**How my Bash script will look like?**

Informations you might need:

- **java**: `usr/bin/java`
- **abc Java program**: `home/john/myapp/abc.class`
- The script will be put inside `home/john/.config/caja/scripts`
- The *john* is my username for *Linux Mint MATE 17.2*, with *caja* as file manager

Below questions might close to my problem:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14601430/how-to-run-a-c-program-in-bash-script-and-give-it-2-arguments
- [Mandatory argument for script to run java program](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/147663/mandatory-argument-for-script-to-run-java-program)
- http://forums.mate-desktop.org/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=812

Comment: Do you only need to know the command to run the java program or are you asking for the complete solution? I don't know how to get the argument but for run the java program you can use "java -jar /home/john/myapp/abc.jar argument"

Comment: I know about that Java thingy., in fact, it's not about Java - but how to make the OS, run a program, in a way that I want, with all requirements supplied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Bash script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
java -cp "$HOME/myapp" abc $CAJA_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS
```

Explanations:

Since my program was placed inside here:

`/home/john/myapp/abc.class`

- I must always use `-cp` java options to locate my "abc" program first.
- The $HOME represents my home directory, `/home/john`,
- The `$CAJA_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS` environment variable represents the path of the **folder I selected**, which eventually being passed as argument to "abc" program.

Note that these solution is made in **caja** specific environment - no guarantee to work in elsewhere.

**Credits to @pranav**, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is Caja-actions Configration tool to add the open with ABC in context menu.

There is command tab in Caja Action tool, there you can provide the script path and the directory argument.
Here is a image of the tool
***http://poundbangbinbash.com/LinuxMint/MATE/Caja/CajaActions/ConfigurationTool.png***

your script would look like

```
!/bin/bash
usr/bin/java [options] home/john/myapp/abc.class $*
```

Comment: Thanks. This is close to my problem. I tried the **script**, but still failed. I'm on my best effort to use and modify your solution. I will inform any progress if necessary.

Comment: Can you add snaps of failure and script.May i can help.

Comment: But first, I think we should go into chat, there's a lot I want to ask - do you prefer email, or any medium?

Comment: I almost forgot, how to I launch "**Caja Actions Configuration Tool**"? I have no idea where to get it.

Comment: You'll find Caja-Actions Configuration Tool under System -> Preferences.

Comment: I will let you know when i will be free for chat

Comment: If you don't have Caja Actions Configuration Tool installed You can get it from here https://github.com/raveit65/caja-actions